# embed video and display in pop up

Tags: video-player

I have installed lightbox plus plugin. I want to display my video in a popup. Or you can suggest me any alternate plugin that can display my video in a pop up. video source is from my own local server.

Comment: You want to embed in a literal popup (aka new browser window)? What is your embed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use [pop up generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/popup-video-generator/) plugin.

Comment: Have you tested this plugin? Does it work on current WP version? I'm just curious as it has low ratings, no updates since 2010 and an unanswered report that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Facybox](http://fancybox.net/) - there's a nice [Fancybox Wordpress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/) - you can easily [embed YouTube Clips](http://fancybox.net/blog#tip4).

Comment: this is a plugin to display images and i want a plugin for embeding video and display in pop up

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Pretty Photo - its easier and will provide greater ease than Lightbox